# call and send data to an aws-lambda function using a node.js script

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, payload

I have a lambda function running on amazon aws cloud. Now I want to make a node.js script to send data from my local system to aws lambda and use callback function to print the same value sent from my node.js code.

Now, to trigger my lambda function from my node.js code, I'm using the following code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// you shouldn't hardcode your keys in production! See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'myaccessKeyId', secretAccessKey: 'mysecretAccessKey',region:'region',correctClockSkew: true});

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'myLambdaFunction', /* required */
  Payload: 'true',
};
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I am new to this lambda function concept, so can anyone help me by telling  how to send data to the required lambda function from the above mentioned code? Using the above code I am able to trigger my lambda function and I am getting in my node app whatever I am printing in it's payload.

I am getting the following error, when I am using a custom string value `( other than 'true', 'false' or 'null')` in payload and the api version which I am using is: `apiVersion: '2015-03-31'` , and the aws-sdk node module was recently installed, so I guess it's up-to-date.
Error message:

```
 { InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'custom_data': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@7d2214ec; line: 1, column: 23]
    at Object.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:43:27)
    at Request.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:37:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:670:12)
  message: 'Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'custom_data\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@7d2214ec; line: 1, column: 23]',
  code: 'InvalidRequestContentException',
  time: 2017-01-16T16:48:38.514Z,
  requestId: '3bee0e2c-dd39-11e6-9df3-5f7a24f73b9d',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 26.112914258191733 } 'InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'custom_data\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@7d2214ec; line: 1, column: 23]\n    at Object.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:43:27)\n    at Request.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:37:8)\n    at Request.callListeners (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)\n    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)\n    at Request.transition (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:670:12)'
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the the [answer provided by Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700471/7311767), have the data that will be loaded into payload constructed as:

```
var data =  {
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: value
}

var datapayload = JSON.stringify(data);

var datalambda= {
    FunctionName: 'LambdaFunctionName',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: datapayload,
    LogType: 'None'
};

// create variable to hold data returned by the Lambda function
var returndata;

lambda.invoke(datalambda, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } 
    else {
        returndata = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
        var log = JSON.stringify(returndata);
        console.log(log);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently sending data to the Lambda function. The data you are sending is the string `'true'`. You send data via the `Payload` property. From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property):

> Payload — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String)
>
> JSON that you want to provide to your Lambda function as input.

Comment: I tried sending other string values, but it throws an error saying the payload value should be 'true' or 'false' or 'null' . Can you kindly try the same thing, with any other string value and let me know whether you are facing the same issue or not. Otherwise there is other issue which I'm missing.

Comment: And one more thing, in order to receive the data I'm sending from node.js app  and display it in my lambda function, should I add any lines of code? Kindly help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code and the actual error message when you try to pass another string?

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version of the AWS SDK?

Comment: I'm recently installed the aws-sdk node module, so I guess it is the latest version of AWS-SDK. And I have edited my original post to show the error I am getting when I used some other string value in payload

Comment: Try using this code to set the Payload value: `json.JSONEncoder().encode(var)` where `var` is your string variable.

Comment: Do I need any specific node module for JSONEncoder? Because, its not working and throwing an error saying json is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got confused and gave you Python code.